# Google Cloud Dataflow (Apache Beam) - how to process gzipped csv files with a header?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have csv (gzip compressed) files in GCS. I want to read these files and send data to BigQuery.

The header info can be changed (although I know all columns in advance), so just dropping a header is not enough, somehow I need to read the first line and append the column info to remaining line.

How is it possible?

I first think I must implement a custom source like this post.
[Reading CSV header with Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297704/reading-csv-header-with-dataflow)
But with this solution, I'm not sure how I can decompress Gzip first. Can I somehow use `withCompressionType` like `TextIO`?
(I found a parameter `compression_type` [in a python Class](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0cc6dd727c674d8724d362e261a7ca84a5ea6a57/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py) but I'm using Java and could not find a similar one in Java `FileBasedSource` class.)

Also I feel this a bit overkilling because it makes a file unsplittable (although in my case it's okay).

Or I can use GoogleCloudStorage and directly read a file and its first line in the first place in my `main()` function then proceed to a pipeline.

But it is also bothersome, so I want to confirm if there is any best practice (the Dataflow way) to read csv file while utilizing a header in Dataflow?

Comment: It should be fairly easy for you to subclass some TextIO transform, and add the special behavior.

Comment: @Pablo is there any example that I can refer to extend TextIO and adding a special behavior? I thought I need to use `Source` to extend a behavior of file processing, and I know how to do that, but by doing so I lose the benefit of auto decompression of a gz file of `TextIO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish correctly, SideInput ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-inputs), [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master-1.x/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TfIdf.java)) is likely the answer here. It will allow the header to be available for processing along side every line of the file.

The general idea is to emit the header as a separate PCollectionView and use this as a SideInput to your per-line processing. You can achieve this using a single pass over your file using SideOutput ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#side-outputs))

If I am reading your question correctly, it sounds like your header contents vary form file to file. If so, you can use `View.asMap` to keep a map of headers from each file. Unfortunately keeping track of the current filename being read is not currently supported natively, but there are work-arrounds discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983621/how-to-get-filename-when-using-file-pattern-match-in-google-cloud-dataflow).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It looks I can (1) First create a PCollection which extracts only a header line (2) Convert it as PCollectionView using Combine.globally and View.asSingleton (3) create another PCollection which extracts all remaining lines (actual data) from a csv with side input of header info obtained in 2. Correct me if I'm wrong. The header is actually different per file as you understand, but for now I decided to submit a job per file, in our case it's acceptable.

Comment: I can read the header and utilize it by the approach above. Thanks:)